# .NET application cannot connect to ServiceController when executed through PsExec

Tags: windows, permissions, automation

I am trying to automate an installation of an application with Packer and Ansible.

At some point the installer of the software, which we have automated using Selenium, checks whether certain Windows Services are running. We have reproduced this specific part with a simple console application:

```csharp
// Connect with ServiceController
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("WAS");
if (sc != null && sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Service is not running");
    return 1;
}
```

When ran manually (right-click, run as administrator), this works.
When ran through Ansible, we get an exception:

```
Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges. InnerException: Access is denied.
```

To execute this process, we use this Ansible task:

```yaml
    - name: Test Service access
      community.windows.win_psexec:
        command: "{{ installation_directory.path }}/servicecontroller-test.exe"
        chdir: "{{ installation_directory.path }}"
        interactive: true
        session: 1
        username: nxservice
        password: ********
        elevated: true
```

The user is created and manipulated like this:

```yaml
    - name: Create service administrator user
      ansible.windows.win_user:
        name: nxservice
        password: ********
        description: "xxxx Application Service User"
        state: present
        groups:
          - Administrators
          - IIS_IUSRS
          - Performance Monitor Users
      register: nxservice_user

    - name: Add account to Log on as a service
      ansible.windows.win_user_right:
        name: SeServiceLogonRight
        users:
          - .\nxservice
        action: add

    - name: Get the existing security descriptor for scmanager
      ansible.windows.win_command: sc sdshow scmanager
      register: scmanager_acl

    - name: Set new security descriptor for scmanager
      ansible.windows.win_command: sc sdset scmanager "D:(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;{{ nxservice_user.sid }}){{ scmanager_acl.stdout_lines[1][2:] }}"

    - name: Grant account to control Process Activation Service
      ansible.windows.win_shell: Grant-CServicePermission -Name WAS -Identity nxservice -FullControl

    - name: Grant account to control World Wide Web Publishing Service
      ansible.windows.win_shell: Grant-CServicePermission -Name W3SVC -Identity nxservice -FullControl
```

But even after all these things, the code is not able to connect to the ServiceController it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Pls chk the following effective value of the following GPO settings at the workstation that you run the code (gpedit.msc or gpresult will show)

User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode
User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode

These two settings affect Local Administrators Group members (not the builtin Administrator user) such as Nxservice user.

If the first setting is Enabled, set the second setting as 'Elevate Without Prompting' and test pls.

Pls not that this setting may weaken the security. If your code runs with this GPO Setting you may choose approving the consent insşde the code.

Comment: I forgot to mention, we also disabled UAC on the server since that is a requirement of the software. So not sure if this setting will have any impact, although I will give it a try.

Comment: I just verified and apparently this undoes the disabling of the UAC, so disabling UAC should cover this too. Thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: I have reproduced the scenario in OS in the lab using RunAs.exe and worked!          sc sdset scmanager D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)(A;;CC;;;AC)(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-3-1024-5)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;S-1-5-....)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)
[SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount>runas /noprofile /env /user:nxservice_user "mmc %windir%\system32\services.msc"
Enter the password for nxservice_user:
Attempting to start mmc C:\Windows\system32\services.msc as user "13D60C39-FB63-4\nxservice_user" ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).